# How difficult is to convert an existing vuejs app to use nuxt SSR?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, seo, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I built a news website using vuejs and for SEO and performance reasons i would like to utilize SSR(Server side rendering) using nuxt, I could find many resources in writing a new nuxt app but nothing on converting an existing vuejs app to nuxt. Has anyone tried this or have recommendations on how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you that you need to create new project as parallel. And convert `Vue` projects to `Nuxt.js` project step by step.

Please watch `Why Use Nuxt.js?` video on https://nuxtjs.org/ home page.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward. Since Nuxt used Vue, all of your components would work the same.

I would create a new blank Nuxt app, then manually migrate each of the pages and components into the new Nuxt app.

Then with Nuxt, you can choose:

1. if you want to use server side rendering (SSR): `npm run build`
2. or statically generate your site: `npm run generate`

EDIT: You can also supercharge your nuxt site with the [nuxt seo package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-seo).